# bathroom vent problems

Tags: bathroom, venting, exhaust

I live in a townhouse(built in 1971 with no privacy wall between my neighbors attic) Between the two units there are 4 static vents and no other source of venting. The attic space would be about 400 sq ft per unit. The bathroom fan vents directly into the attic and since I have no control over adding more vents is it ok to just keep as is, or should I hook up a line to the static vent?

Comment: `fan vents directly into the attic` .... do you get heavy moisture buildup in the attic in winter months?

Answer (score 1):

The code requires the air from a bathroom be, “exhausted directly to the exterior.”  Also, “air from bathrooms with tubs, showers or spas shall not be exhausted to attics or crawl spaces.” (See ICC M1507.2.)

If the landlord balks, tell him you’re developing a mold issue and you’re going to contact the local Building Official.